# Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

I am using Laravel Mail function to send email. The following is my `app/config/mail.php` file settings.

```
'driver' => 'sendmail',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'email@gmail.com', 'name' => 'MyName'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'myUsername',
'password' => "password",
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Controller Mail Method

```
//Send Mail     
Mail::send('sendMail', array('key' => 'value'), function($message)
{
    $message->to('EmailId@hotmail.com', 'Sender Name')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

When I run the code it gives me following error message:

> Swift_TransportException
>
> Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

I have created a `SendMail.php` file in view which contains some data.

How do I resolve this error message?

Comment: have you enabled two step verification for the gmail account you are using?

Comment: For anyone using SELinux: check SELinux audit...

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This problem can generally occur when you do not enable two step verification for the `gmail` account (which can be done [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)) you are using to send an `email`. So first, enable `two step verification`, you can find plenty of resources for enabling two step verification. After you enable it, then you have to create an `app password`. And use the `app password` in your `.env` file. When you are done with it, your `.env` file will look something like.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and your `mail.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => '<<your email>>', 'name' => '<<any name>>'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

After doing so, run `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`, then check, email should work.

Comment: I have looked everywhere and couldn't find the solution, but you totally saved my life!!. Thank you so much!!. I'm voting your answer up!

Comment: Nice! It's working now. I think that is the proper answer for this error.

Comment: I had the same issue with Yii2 and mailer. To me the key was to endorse the gmail account using the phone number. I didn't do everything suggested here, just following the yii2 documentation for mailer class implementation and this thing with phone number linking.

Comment: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: thanks so much! I thought just allowing less secure app access will make it work but just waste my time!

Comment: Thanks man for your perfect answer. You saved me. Upvoted your answer

Answer (score 36):

In my case I had to set the

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465           <<<<<<<------------------------- (FOCUS THIS)
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>

MAIL_ENCRYPTION= ssl    <<<<<<<------------------------- (FOCUS THIS)
```

to work it.. Might be useful.
Rest of the code was same as @Sid said.

And I think that editing both environment file and app/config/mail.php is unnecessary. Just use one method.

**Edit as per the comment by @Zan**

If you need to enable **tls** protection use following settings.

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION= tls
```

See [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/DE5mVMSh1vk/3FCHcNLAr6kJ) for some other gmail settings

Comment: SSL is considered insecure now: https://www.entrust.com/lp/poodle-ssl-3-0-fallback-vulnerability/ It's better to follow the 'tls' answers.

Comment: @JanŻankowski True. I edited the answer. You may find other settings as well

Answer (score 18):

What helped me... changing sendmail parameters from -bs to -t.

```
'sendmail' => '/your/sendmail/path -t',
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! How did you come to that idea?

Comment: You need to provide more information that where should we add this or change this

Comment: From the Swiftmail docs:

You can run the Sendmail Transport in two different modes specified by command line flags:

"-bs" runs in SMTP mode so theoretically it will act like the SMTP Transport.
"-t" runs in piped mode with no feedback, but theoretically faster, though not advised.
You can think of the Sendmail Transport as a sort of asynchronous SMTP Transport -- though if you have problems with delivery failures you should try using the SMTP Transport instead. Swift Mailer isn't doing the work here, it's simply passing the work to somebody else (i.e. sendmail).

Comment: If using 'sendmail -t' you will not be aware of any failures until they bounce (i.e. send() will always return 100% success).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Swift Mailer:
please ensure that your $transport variable is similar to the below,
based on tests i have done, that error results from ssl and port misconfiguration.
**note: you must include 'ssl' or 'tls' in the transport variable.**

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
  ->setUsername(you@example.com)
  ->setPassword(password)
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('News Letter Subscription'))
  ->setFrom(['app@example.com' => 'A Name'])
  ->setTo(['someone@example.com' => 'A Name'])
  ->setBody('your message body')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. After researching too much on Google and StackOverflow. I found a solution very simple

First, you need to set environment like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=example44
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com
```

you have to change your Gmail address and password

Now you have to on less secure apps by following this link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the port. I first incorrectly used port 465, which works for `SSL` but not `TLS`. So the key thing was changing the port to 587.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by activating the less secure Application Access setting of my Google account and the following environment variable settings:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= your email
MAIL_PASSWORD= your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```