# how to send email in laravel 5 using gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5

I want to send mail using my laravel application but i got some problems it send error saying my smtp server can't be reached .

my mail configation

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'do not replay'],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


];
```

my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:XewgRN8avAbSmWxu2IXcB5b3AhwSfdffm9VmpT/0A8k=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=clear
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myapppaswword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

but it generate this error

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 74.125.206.108 (74.125.206.108:587), connect error 10060
"
```

I searched for solution but i could not find one any help will be appreciated

Comment: Enable less secure apps first https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find what you need in [this linked post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32696418/59975)

> This problem can generally occur when you do not enable two step
>   verification for the gmail account you are using to send an email. So
>   first, enable two step verification, you can find plenty of resources
>   for enabling two step verification. After you enable it, then you have
>   to create an app password. And use the app password in your .env file.

Comment: I have enabled two step verification and use my application password.