# Expected response code 220 but got code "" with message ""

Tags: php, laravel, email, post, smtp

Every time I submit the contact form on my Laravel application I receive the error message in the title. I've followed the recommendation in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693528/expected-response-code-220-but-got-code-with-message-in-laravel), but it has had no effect even after `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`. Here's the relevant code:

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),    
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

I was under the impression from the documentation that the global 'from' wouldn't fire unless no other from address was provided, but in my controller for the mail, I specified the address supplied to the contact form as the 'from,' is that a conflict point somehow? It doesn't seem to be from the error message details.

Because the contact form is not a distinct view but the bottom of the mainpage view, the Controller function lives in **PageController**

```
public function postContact(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [

      'email' => 'required|email',
      'subject' => 'required|min:3',
      'message' => 'required|min:10'
    ]);

    $data = array(
      'email' => $request->email,
      'subject' => $request->subject,
      'mailbody' => $request->message
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
      $message->from($data['email']);
      $message->to('username@gmail.com');
      $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
  }
```

Comment: change the port from 465 to 587 and MAIL_ENCRYPTION= ssl.
Also allow google app less secure from google settings.

Comment: This got rid of the old error but now I'm getting "Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]"

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693528/expected-response-code-220-but-got-code-with-message-in-laravel?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: That is in fact the answer I link in the original question above as having read it, applied the suggestions, and not having them work.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should define mail sender (`MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`) as your gmail which you want to use send emails with.

for example, if your `MAIL_USERNAME` at `.env` is **example@gmail.com** you should define your `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` (or of course `$mail->from()`) as **example@gmail.com**.

I don't think gmail allows you send emails as another user (another address).

Answer (score 1):

[Similar problem](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-an-email-on-laravel-5)
587 port

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=address@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secreat
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Update above code in Your .env file and then run these commands in terminal

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.. It is working fine when i changed EMAIL_ENCRYPTION
It was `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tps'),` before
I change it to `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),`