# Laravel mail error: Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I'm developing a new Laravel application. When I'm using mail to send messages via contact form in my website, I'm getting the following error:

> Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

I'm developing in my local environment but using my business mail to get messages.

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\SendMessage;
use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class SendMessageController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            "email" => "required|email",
            "message" => "min:10",
            "subject" => "min:3"
        ]);


        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $company = $request->company;
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $message = $request->message;

        Mail::to("audit@auditors.uz")->send(new SendEmail($subject, $message));

        Session::flash("success", "Your email was sent");

        return back();
    }
}

?>
```

My mailing function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $sub;
    public $mese;
    public function __construct($subject, $message)
    {
        $this->sub = $subject;
        $this->mes = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $e_subject = $this->sub;
        $e_message = $this->mes;
        return $this->view('emails.contact', compact("e_message"))->subject($e_subject);
    }
}
?>
```

My `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.auditors.uz
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=audit@auditors.uz
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I googled it a lot, but did not find the appropriate answer. If anybody of you can help me, I'll be really happy. Because I've been looking for a solution for a long time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `MAIL_DRIVER` is set to `mail`, which does not exist by default. If you are using an SMTP mail server, you should use `smtp` as the driver.

Please make sure that your email provider supports port 465 and TLS encryption. Most of the providers support these automatically though.

Comment: I've solved previous problem with your help. But now I'm taking the error: Swift_TransportException thrown with message "Expected response code 220 but got an empty response"

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think this answer is able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32696418/3625118

If my answer solved your issue, please accept it, so other visitors are able to find a solution easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAIL_DRIVER="smtp"`

Do not forget to Re-Serve or clear cache of Laravel
[ `php artisan optimize:clear` / `php artisan config:clear` / `php artisan cache:clear` ]