# How to get latest record on a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Users have plans stored in the `invoices` table. These plans are monthly based.

## What I need to do

I want to add a new row for user if his plan expire date has reached and they didn't renew their plans (I don't want to update old one)

## The issue is

Each user has unlimited rows in `invoices` table as they renew each month. Now when I try to retrieve their latest row and check the expiring date it gets other rows of those users as well.

## Example

1. My user has `3 rows` in `invoices`
2. two of them already expired and renewed, the current one is `id=3`
3. when I try to expire this `id=3` and create `id=4` for this user
4. it gets all `3 rows` and send 3 emails to the user.

## Code

```
public function handle()
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::where('plan_expire', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
        $current = Carbon::now();
        $expiredatetime = $current->addDays(30);
        $useType = Type::where('name', 'Free')->first();

        foreach($invoices as $invoice)
        {
            Invoice::create([
                'user_id' => $invoice->user->id,
                'type_id' => $useType->id,
                'amount' => $useType->price,
                'status' => 'Approved',
                'plan_expire' => $expiredatetime->toDateTimeString(),
            ]);
            Mail::to($invoice->user->email)->send(new UserPlansReset($invoice));
        }
    }
```

`User model`

```
public function invoices()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
}
```

`Invoice model`

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'type_id', 'amount', 'status', 'plan_expire',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'plan_expire' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

## Question

Do you have any idea how I can only get users latest row in `invoices` table?

## Update

based on answers below I changed my code to:

```
$current = Carbon::now();
        $expiredatetime = $current->addDays(30);
        $useType = Type::where('name', 'Free')->first();

        $users = User::all();
        foreach($users as $user){
          $latestInvoice = $user->invoices()->latest()->first();

          if(!empty($latestInvoice) && $latestInvoice->plan_expire <= Carbon::now()){
              Invoice::create([
                  'user_id' => $user->id,
                  'type_id' => $useType->id,
                  'amount' => $useType->price,
                  'status' => 'Approved',
                  'plan_expire' => $expiredatetime->toDateTimeString(),
              ]);
              Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserPlansReset($user));
          }
        }
```

Now this function will return

```
Expected response code 220 but got an empty response
```

and **wont send emails**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in Invoice model, add plan_expire in $dates variable instead of $casts :

```
protected $dates = ["plan_expire"];
```

You can try like this :

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user){

  $latestInvoice = $user->invoices()->latest()->first();

  if($latestInvoice->plan_expire->isPast()){

       //create invoice and mailed it
  }
  //other steup

}
```

For Email send return empty response issue , You can check this question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693528/expected-response-code-220-but-got-code-with-message-in-laravel)

Comment: no, you got me wrong. is not about 1 user, i need to check all users plans, this is command will be run by schedule so it does the job automatically.

Comment: this returns `Expected response code 220 but got an empty response`  `PS` it does the database job but somehow it prevent sending emails.

Comment: oh! when i commented mailing part it returns `Trying to get property 'plan_expire' of non-object` `note` as this command runs every minute we need to avoid this error in case there is no expired plans

Answer (score 0):

Find expired invoices, group by user id and order by `plan_expire` and select first record in each group.

MySQL server version < 8 don't have window functions that may make it easier to do row numbering in matched rows.

A workaround is to set client variables that can be used to number invoices by the same user starting from 1 and selecting only the first ones.

```php
$now = Carbon::now();
$nowDS = $now->toDateTimeString();

$expired_invoices = "
SET @rownum := 0;
SET @userid := NULL;

SELECT *, uid as user_id, plan_expire 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        @rownum := CASE
            WHEN @userid = uid 
            THEN @rownum + 1
            ELSE 1
            END AS rn,
        @userid := user_id AS uid,
        num
    FROM invoices AS i
    WHERE plan_expire <= $nowDS
    ORDER BY user_id, plan_expire DESC
) AS num_invoices WHERE rn = 1;
"

$invoices = DB::select($expired_invoices);
```

Now, `$invoices` can be iterated over and mail sent to the owner of it.

```
$expiredatetime = $now->addDays(30);
$useType = Type::where('name', 'Free')->first();
$users = User::all();


foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
{
    Invoice::create([
        'user_id' => $invoice->user_id,
        'type_id' => $useType->id,
        'amount' => $useType->price,
        'status' => 'Approved',
        'plan_expire' => $expiredatetime,
    ]);

    $user = $users->find(['id' => $invoice->user_id]);
    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserPlansReset($user));
}
```

Comment: it returns `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(user_id), plan_expire from `invoices` where `plan_expire` <= ? group by `user_i' at line 1 (SQL: select first(user_id), plan_expire from `invoices` where `plan_expire` <= 2019-04-18 14:01:03 group by `user_id` order by `plan_expire` desc)`